# マルチプロセスで起動したタスクに名前を付ける方法

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

## 概要

マルチプロセスで動作させているプロセスタスクをタスクマネージャーで監視すると、全てPythonという名前になってしまいます。
これを任意に名前に変更する方法はあるのでしょうか？

multiprocessing.Processメソッドの引数nameを代入しても変化ありません。

[image: タスクマネージャー]

Comment: これらの記事が使えるかもしれません。[Pythonプログラムのプロセス名を設定する](https://qiita.com/cubicdaiya/items/ca4d11918348dc828e15), [Pythonのsetproctitleモジュールでプロセス名を設定する](https://aoishi.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/01/28/031545)

Comment: 想定しているのは Windows 環境でしょうか？ OS によって対応方法が異なる可能性があるので、タグもしくは本文で OS 環境も明示しておいた方が具体的な回答に繋がるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。対象OSはWindows10/11です。setproctitleのプロジェクトページにも説明がありましたが、Windowsでは名前を変更できないと記述されています。

Comment: 代替案的には、コマンドラインオプションに説明用の文字列を指定出来るようにしておいて、タスクマネージャーの表示欄を追加して識別するとか出来るのでは？ [プロセスのコマンドラインを表示する方法](https://tooljp.com/qa/CommanLine-in-TaskManager-5156.html)

Comment: なるほど。コマンドラインの表示も一つの方法ですね。